# How find all links (URL) in a webpage and add a string at the end of all of them?

Tags: php, html, regex, string, web-crawler

Hey so what I am trying to acheive is get all links on page using

```
preg_match_all("/<a(?:[^>]*)href=\"([^\"]*)\"(?:[^>]*)>(?:[^<]*)<\/a>/is"
```

and then adding "|Cookie=" to the end of each url while keeping the source of page the exact same.

For example:
Let's say I find the following links in my scraped page "`example.com/index.html` and `example2.com/index.html`"

I want them to be changed to "`example.com/index.html|Cookie=xxx`" and "`example2.com/index.html|Cookie=xxx`"

So sorry if my question is too vague. I have no clue how to start :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need regular expression for this, you can use **DOM** to do this for you.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
@$doc->loadHTML($html); // load the HTML data

foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName('a') as $link) {
   $link->setAttribute('href', $link->getAttribute('href').'|Cookie=xxx');
}

echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

Comment: and what happens of the link is not in a tag <a> ?

Comment: This is specifically for `a` tags, which is what the OP is wanting.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the url just replace `$content = file_get_contents('URL');`

```
<?php

$content = '<html>
<title>Random Website I am Crawling</title>
<body>
Click <a href="http://clicklink.com">here</a> for foobar
Another site is http://foobar.com
</body>
</html>';

$regex = "((https?|ftp)\:\/\/)?"; // SCHEME
$regex .= "([a-z0-9+!*(),;?&=\$_.-]+(\:[a-z0-9+!*(),;?&=\$_.-]+)?@)?"; // User and Pass
$regex .= "([a-z0-9-.]*)\.([a-z]{2,4})"; // Host or IP
$regex .= "(\:[0-9]{2,5})?"; // Port
$regex .= "(\/([a-z0-9+\$_-]\.?)+)*\/?"; // Path
$regex .= "(\?[a-z+&\$_.-][a-z0-9;:@&%=+\/\$_.-]*)?"; // GET Query
$regex .= "(#[a-z_.-][a-z0-9+\$_.-]*)?"; // Anchor

$pattern = "/$regex/";

$newContent = preg_replace($pattern, '${0}|Cookie=xxx', $content);
echo $newContent;
```

Output:

```
<html>
<title>Random Website I am Crawling</title>
<body>
Click <a href="http://clicklink.com|Cookie=xxx">here</a> for foobar
Another site is http://foobar.com|Cookie=xxx
</body>
```